# Stopping an if clause along with the whole PHP script, but not HTML

Tags: php, exit

I've been having this problem for around an hour, and have searched the internet for answers. I've checked the PHP documentation, looked around, Googled, nothing.

Anyways, my problem is that after I try to validate something (and it's wrong), if I use **exit;** it will also stop the HTML after. Here's what I'm talking about:

```
if ($_POST['exampleEmail'] == "")
{
    echo "Please enter an e-mail."; //Now I want only the PHP script to stop, however...
    exit; //If I use exit, then the HTML after this script (footer) doesn't show.
}
```

If anyone can help, please do. I've tried using break, but to no avail, since it's only for loops and switches.

If there is a better/more correct (or simply correct if this is the wrong way), please share. I've had this problem in the past, and I just used exit then.

Thanks.

Comment: I believe you can exit the current php `if` loop with a `return` (or possibly `break`, I forget) statement. Possibly you could also assign a variable and check for the presence of that variable to determine whether to execute any further checks?

Comment: Yeah, thanks everyone ^_^ I told the post to send me emails on new replies, but I guess it forgot O.o

Answer (score 4):

Just wrap the rest of the script in a new `if` block:

```
$execute = true;

// HTML here...
if (empty($_POST['exampleEmail'])) {
    echo "Please enter an e-mail.";
    $execute = false;
}
// HTML here...
if ($execute) {
    // do stuff only if execute is still true.
}
// HTML here...
```

Now that this is working for you, I advise you to do some research into separating your presentation and your logic.  There's a lot of tutorials and blogs on the subject, you just need to start searching.

Comment: Thanks! Actually, I found a similar method while browsing the internet, but I guess I forgot it. Thanks again! Oh, and about the logic, that's similar to game development, Event Handling -> Logic -> Rendering, right? If so, I have a basic setup in mind :)

Comment: Yes, it is similar.  In web development, the Model-View-Controller architecture is usually used for this.

Answer (score 2):

**You should use an if-statement in PHP**

```
if ($_POST['exampleEmail'] == "")
{
    echo "Please enter an e-mail.";
    $stop_script = true; //stop the script
}
else    $stop_script = false; //or continue the script

if($stop_script === false)
{
    //php scripts
}

//html
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `break` http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php instead. But you probably have a structural Problem if it comes to this usecase in the first place.